# How do I further optimize this Data Structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I was recently asked to build a data structure that supports four operations, namely,

1. Push: Add an element to the DS.
2. Pop: Remove the last pushed element.
3. Find_max: Find the maximum element out of the currently stored elements.
4. Pop_max: Remove the maximum element from the DS.

The elements are integers.

Here is the solution I suggested:

1. Take a stack.
2. Store a pair of elements in it. The pair should be (element, max_so_far), where *element* is the element at that index and *max_so_far* is the maximum valued element seen so far.
3. While pushing an element into the stack, check the *max_so_far* of the topmost stack element. If current number is greater than that, put the current pair's *max_so_far* value as the current element's value, else store the previous *max_so_far*. This mean that pushing would simply be an `O(1)` operation.
4. For `pop`, simply pop an element out of the stack. Again, this operation is `O(1)`.
5. For `Find_max`, return the value of the *max_so_far* of the topmost element in the stack. Again, `O(1)`.
6. Popping the max element would involve going through the stack and explicitly removing the max element and pushing back the elements on top of it, after allotting new *max_so_far* values. This would be linear.

I was asked to improve it, but I couldn't.

In terms of time complexity, the overall time can be improved if all operations happen in `O(logn)`, I guess. How to do that, is something I'm unable to get.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: Coding this is very trivial. The problem isn't with the code, but the algorithm.

Comment: When you do get an implementation coded and working, think about posting it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) :) They'll have pointers about the *code* as well as the algorithm.

Comment: A lot depends on how many items you expect to have, and how often each operation will be called

Comment: @IanRingrose yep! You're right. But since we're told to build a data structure, we can safely assume that each method will be called in the same frequency. That being the case, my solution would take quadratic time for O(n) operations whereas the accepted solution would take O(nlogn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to store pointers to the elements in a doubly-linked list, and also in a [max-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) data structure (sorted by value).

Each element would store its position in the doubly-linked list and also in the max-heap.

In this case all of your operations would require O(1) time in the doubly-linked list, plus O(log(n)) time in the heap data structure.

Comment: Great solution! Simple and elegant.

Comment: I don't see how the DLL is helping here. `find_max` is O(1), the rest O(log(n)) with a heap alone.

Comment: +1: The DLL provides the insertion order required by the pop() function.

Answer (score 5):

One way to get O(log n)-time operations is to mash up two data structures, in this case a doubly linked list and a priority queue (a pairing heap is a good choice) . We have a node structure like

```
struct Node {
    Node *previous, *next;  // doubly linked list
    Node **back, *child, *sibling;  // pairing heap
    int value;
} list_head, *heap_root;
```

Now, to push, we push in both structures. To find_max, we return the value of the root of the pairing heap. To pop or pop_max, we pop from the appropriate data structure and then use the other node pointers to delete in the other data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you need to find elements by quality A (value), and also by quality B (insert order), then you start eyeballing a data structure that actually has two data structures inside that reference each other, or are otherwise interleaved.

For instance: two maps that who's keys are quality A and quality B, who's values are a shared pointer to a struct that contains iterators back to both maps, and the value.  Then you have log(n) to find an element via either quality, and erasure is ~O(logn) to remove the two iterators from either map.

```
struct hybrid {
    struct value {
        std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<value>>::iterator name_iter;
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<value>>::iterator height_iter;
        mountain value;
    };
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<value>> name_map;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<value>> height_map;

    mountain& find_by_name(std::string s) {return name_map[s]->value;}
    mountain& find_by_height(int height h) {return height_map[s]->value;}
    void erase_by_name(std::string s) {
        value& v = name_map[s];
        name_map.erase(v.name_iter);
        height_iter.erase(v.height_iter); //note that this invalidates the reference v
    }
};
```

However, in your case, you can do even better than this O(logn), since you only need "the most recent" and "the next highest".  To make "pop highest" fast, you need a fast way to detect the next highest, which means that needs to be precalculated at insert.  To find the "height" position relative to the rest, you need a map of some sort. To make "pop most recent" fast, you need a fast way to detect the next most recent, but that's trivially calculated.  I'd recommend creating a map or heap of nodes, where keys are the value for finding the max, and the values are a pointer to the next most recent value.  This gives you O(logn) insert, O(1) find most recent, O(1) or O(logn) find maximum value (depending on implementation), and ~O(logn) erasure by either index.

Comment: Thank you for the extra insight.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I'd figured erasure by iterator of the last node is going to be insanely close to O(1), but upon review, the complexity is indeed log(n).

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this is:-

Create max-heap with elements. In this way we will be able to get/delete max-element in O(1) operations.
Along with this we can maintain a pointer to last pushed element.And as far as I know delete in heaps can be constructed in O(log n).